# Checkout page on refresh issue

Tags: checkout-page, magento2-enterprise

I have enabled Google Tag Manager from admin panel and in checkout page when I refresh the page new address disappears. If I disable GTM checkout page works properly. Anybody faced the same issue? Any solution for this ?

Comment: Which magento version? write more .

Comment: I am using magento 2 - EE and  it shows shipping address under shippingAddressFromData  in localstorage mage-cache-storage. But when I refresh the page values become null. And checkoutData->get method returns null